# Can I design web or HTML pages(with Javascript & css support) using IBM Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

We are new to IBM Bluemix & Cloud based PAAS. 
We are learning about application development & deployment in IBM Bluemix.
Our Target technology stack is Java, PHP, Python, Javascript, CSS (Style sheet for web pages).

Can I design web or HTML pages(with Javascript & css support) using IBM Bluemix ?

If this option is present, then I can develop web pages faster and get my applications immediately to prospective customers.

Answer (score 0):

All the technologies you have mentioned can be supported in Bluemix by using various buildpacks. For the HTML based project (Javascript + css) you can use the Liberty Runtime. Just go to the Catalog and create an application using the Liberty Runtime. This will give you a skeleton of HTML application you can build on.